# Read input file java

Tags: java, input

I am fairly new to programming, so bear with me.

I am trying to read an input file, "1.in" and assign the first line to a variable, the second to another variable, and so on. The file is fairly short, 100 lines. How do I go about doing this? I tried researching it on the internet, but i didn't really understand the results. The only type of input i know right now is by using the scanner class, but that requires manual input.

Comment: `The only type of input i know right now is by using the scanner class, but that requires manual input.` That is wrong. `Scanner` works with every ("primitive") `InputStream`. It doesn't matter if the data comes from a file, an user or a webpage (for example).

Comment: @Tom then how do I use Scanner for what I want to do?

Comment: Read the answer of @TomášGašpar for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use some data structure to hold your data. 
If you know size of your file, array is the best option. Or you can use LinkedList, ArrayList

For Example

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
File file = new File("data.txt");

    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            list.add(line);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the linked list? Also, why is it necessary for the try...catch? I never needed it before.